# Setting up a batch action in Acrobat for adding a barcode footer to a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, batch-processing, adobe-acrobat

I'll make a point to be as detailed as I can with this. My company does sublimation printing for retail items. To make sure items are correctly identified on the production table, each item has to have a barcode added to it, along with its file name - which has to be mirrored since our printing software mirrors images for the sublimation printing process (the barcode doesn't need mirroring). We had previously done this by using a photoshop batch action that added an additional 1 inch of white space at the bottom of the file, then created the barcode and filename using javascript set up to create text layers based on the file's naming structure. It would align the barcode to the lower right corner, and center the file name as well.

Now, we've moved beyond using JPEGs for sublimation printing because PDFs tend to work better with our printing software. The only issue being is that I've been unable to replicate the previously mentioned batch action in Acrobat (we're still using Acrobat 9 Pro, as well), since I little to no experience setting up batch actions in Acrobat.

Is there a way to set up a batch action that would do what our Photoshop version did? I know it's possible to add a barcode to a PDF via a Javascript action, but in our case, it needs to be in a very specific place in the layout.

Comment: Acrobat 9 javascript documentation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JavaScript_SectionPage.70.1.html

Comment: Javascript/vbscript/applescript can be invoked from outside the {Adobe Program} environment (i.e. the OS level). One way might be to invoke PS, make an image with a specific filename flopped and add barcode, and then save'n'place that image in the PDF. I have no experience scripting Acrobat.

Comment: We're currently using Photoshop to do it, but are saving the files with the barcodes as EPS files and dropping them into Acrobat Distiller (which gives us a nicer balance between file size and quality than saving as a PDF directly from Photoshop did...).

Comment: It is possible to specify coordinates via scripts, and you can query the document size to calculate placement.

Comment: does your printer use postscript as printing  language? because it would be pretty easy to preprocess the code with merging two eps sources.

Comment: I'd assume it does, however we're required to use Versaworks to print our files and it's limited in what it can do.  This NEEDS to be completely in acrobat.

I don't know why I need to clarify what we're looking for, but I'm going to see if I can't break this down better.

I need a script that queries the size of the PDF then activates "Crop Pages" entering a custom page size under "Change Page Size" that is the PDF's original width and it's original height +1 inch, with 1 inch under Y Offset.

Comment: It also needs to query other dimensions to place the file name and barcode in the bottom one inch (we don't need a script to generate the barcode, as we have a font installed that allows us to type them out as we need - it just needs to be automated).  The major issue being that while I know the commands I need to automate, I know a ridiculously small amount of Javascript.  I need some help figuring out that part.

Answer (score -3):

so how about this found on google 
[jasper barcode](http://www.keepautomation.com/products/barcode_fonts/)

Comment: Hello Leona, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please add a bit more info about what we can find at the link? That way, your answer will stsill be valuable in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is exactly why we don't really like link-only answers here. Don't be discouraged, we *are* happy to have you here and we know that using the site can be a learning curve. Thanks again!